# Mysql workbench out of memory error code 23 & 24

Tags: mysql, memory, out-of-memory

I have a dump file which has the length 281 Million, but only about 1900 lines.

When I try to import this sql file I am getting memory errors. While importing, I saw that there is still unused memory. I searched on the web but could not find a solution. This is my error message:

```
ERROR 23 (HY000) at line 143: Out of resources when opening file '.\mydb\mytable#P#mycolumn#SP#refereesp70.MYD' (Errcode: 24)
```

**Mysql was an older version i upgraded now the problem has gone thanks you all...**

Comment: are you trying to import the file in MySql Workbench or into a database?

Comment: i am trying to import a table script to a database

Comment: Maybe it is possible to break the script in smaller bits? You can then import those one by one. Or maybe it helps to try to import it on the command-line?

Answer (score 0):

Change/upgrade your system limits for mysql.

edit /etc/security/limits.conf file 
 --add lines below,  if mysql start from mysql user
 mysql soft nofile 2048
 mysql hard nofile 2058